# trying to display records from database using php

Tags: php, sql

this is my first question here so feedback on how to improve my questions would be appreciated.

I am trying to display records from a database using PHP.
Here is the code

```
<?php
$dbConn = new mysqli('localhost', 'twa037', 'twa037Dg', 'autoservice037');
if($dbConn->connect_error) {
    die("failed to connect to the database: " . $dbConn->connect_error);
}
else
{
    echo "success";
}

    $sql = "select * from customer ";
    if ($dbConn->query($sql) ) 
        {
            echo "query successful";    
        }

     while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())  {

    echo $row['familyName'];
    } 

    $dbconn->close();

    ?>
```

I am able to connect to the database and also the query appears to be working fine as it is displaying "success" and "query successfull".
However, I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()
>   on string

Before you guys suggest this could be a duplicate of another post, I have noticed that in the other posts they have used the same code as I have without an issue.

Comment: Sorry guys, is there any way i can know why my question is being down voted for?
Just so i know for the future

Comment: You are trying to call fetch_assoc on the string variable that contains your SQL _code_, which is wrong - you need to call it on the result of the executed query. Simply checking the example the manual provides would have already shown you how to use this properly - https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Probably because you didn't do a basic research before asking. Check this example(s): https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query` returns a result on that you can call `fetch_assoc()`. not on the querystring itself.

```
if ($result = $dbConn->query($sql) ) 
    {
        echo "query successful";    
    }

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
```

more informations you can find [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) <=> while($row = $dbConn->query($sql)->fetch_assoc())
```